Line graph of an integral graph.
The line graph $L(G)$ of a simple, undirected graph $G$ is defined as follows: the vertices of $L(G)$ are the edges of $G$ and two vertices in $L(G)$ are adjacent if and only if the corresponding edges in $G$ are incident, i.e., they share a common vertex.
In the paper entitled as "Which graphs have integral spectra?" by F. Harary and A.J. Schwenk ($1974$), I came across a result stating that,
If $G$ is integral, so is its line graph.(Corollary 6)
It is known that if $G$ is $r$-regular with $n$ vertices and $m=nr/2$ edges, then its line graph is $(2r-2)$-regular whose spectrum is given by the multiset: $\lbrace{(\lambda_i+r-2)^{[1]},(-2)^{[m-n]}}\rbrace$ where $i=1,2,\ldots,n$ and the exponent denotes the multiplicity of the corresponding eigenvalue.
So it follows clearly that if $G$ is a regular, integral graph, so is $L(G)$.
Therefore my doubt is regarding Corollary 6 mentioned above. How does it follow if we disregard the regularity condition of $G$? Even the Wikipedia page for Integral graph states the same with the mention of the same reference.
